# Visual c++ 2008 not showing runtime errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm working on a project in Visual C++ 2008 Express and I have noticed that the program has stopped saying that there are run-time errors. Whenever I run the program, it just loads the latest stable build. It doesn't even show me the errors, because they disappear after launch. I want to know what is wrong with my code and fix it, but it just wouldn't show me the errors. It's my first program in Visual C++ and I have to do it until tomorrow. Please help!

EDIT: Solved, look in my comment

Comment: Step through your code in the debugger and see where it fails.

Comment: I've solved it by Rebuilding Solution (Ctrl+Alt+F7).

Comment: Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run.  "On Run, when build or deployment error occurs" setting, change it to "Do no launch".